# Differentiate between one and two finger swipe-UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, swipe-gesture, flipview, pivotitem

In our windows 10 app we are using a flipview inside a pivot item. Now i want the items in flipview to change when i swipe with one finger and if swiped with two fingers the pivot item should change. How can i achieve this?